# How many ways to move around parentheses for finite tensor products?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have $n$ elements where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in a place where tensor products make since and are not strict, say $a_1,\cdots, a_n$. Suppose we only know that $a_i\otimes a_{j}$ is defined for all $i,j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$. How many ways are there to move around the parenthesis for tensoring all the elements together if we have the $a_i$'s in numerical order?

I know for 3 elements, there is two ways.

$(a\otimes b)\otimes c$

$a\otimes (b\otimes c)$

For four elements, there are 5 ways.

$(a\otimes b)\otimes (c\otimes d)$

$a\otimes(b\otimes(c\otimes d))$

$a\otimes ((b\otimes c)\otimes d)$

$(a\otimes(b\otimes c))\otimes d$

$((a\otimes b)\otimes c)\otimes d$

I do not know for any higher number. I am trying to use this to construct graphs which forms a single shape and then construct an operad based on this information whose algebras are precisely symmetric monoidal categories with a strict unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have n elements, the answer seems to be ${1\over n}{2(n-1)\choose n-1} $, which is the (n-1)-th [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), which are closely related whit this kind of problems